# Chained Monos and retry

Tags: java, project-reactor

Wrote a class as below:

```
class KeyFetcher {
    String key = "";

    Mono getKeys() {
        try {
            key = keyService.getKeys();
            if(key == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException("key value is null");
            } else {
                this.key = key;
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return Mono.error(e);
        }
        return Mono.just(key)
    }

    @Scheduled // spring scheduler
    void fetchDataFromExternalService() {
        client.fetchData(key) // returns Mono
        .retry(3)
        .map(this::processResponse)
        .doOnError(this::handleError)
        .subscribe();
    }
}
```

I want to modify the `fetchDataFromExternalService` method to include the getKeys() also before calling external service, and retry three times on both methods. Retry will be like:

1. get keys - try 3 times on failure - then go to handleError and do not call external service.
2. if key are fetched within 3 retry boundary, then now fetch data from external service with max 3 retries.
3. if error encountered in client.fetchData(), then go to handleError but not retry getKeys9) again.

I tried below:

```
Mono.defer(()-> getKeys())
    .flatMap(obj -> client.fetchData(key))
    .retry(3)
    .map(this::processResponse)
    .doOnError(this::handleError)
    .subscribe();
```

But the problem is that when getKey() returns response in say 2nd retry, it enters fetchData(), but if this methods throws exception, it enters handleError() **before again re-entering getKey() which is not desirable**. All I want is once getKey() retry is exhausted, control should enter handleError() and close the Mono. Same for fetchData(). I think I am doing something wrong above, but need suggestion as I am new to this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are well describing your issue, and if you apply strictly your description to your code, you will get what you need.

In your code sample, you create a pipeline that fetch a key, then fetch data. Therefore, the retry is applied to the entire chain, because it receive a publisher that already chain both actions.

You want:

1. to fetch a key with 3 max retries:

   ```java
   Mono<Key> getKeyWithRetry = Mono.defer(() -> getKeys()).retry(3);
   ```
2. Fetch data from an input key, with retry:

   ```java
   Function<Key, Mono<Data>> fetchDataWithRetry = key -> fetchData(key).retry(3)
   ```
3. And finally, assemble all that with error handling:

   ```java
   getKeyWithRetry()
       .flatMap(fetchDataWithRetry)
       .map(this::processResponse)
       .doOnError(this::handleError)
       .subscribe();
   ```